# Mysql returns empty result after table update

Tags: mysql

I have a table that contains product code in my case it is called unic and product's category called CatText table it self called sc_products. An other table called t26_replacebleitems contains 2 of those product codes product itself called unicitem and replacement to it called unicreplacement. I am querying them this way:

```
SELECT 
    unicitem, unicreplacement, 
    sc_products.product_code, sc_products.productID,    
    sc_products.brief_description_ru, sc_products.name_ru, 
    price.postavchik as suupplier, sc_group_discounts.`action`, 
    sc_group_discounts.procent, price.Price as Price, price.in_stock, price.supplier 
FROM 
    sc_products 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    t26_replaceable_items ON (sc_products.unic = t26_replaceable_items.unicreplacement) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    sc_group_discounts ON (sc_products.item_group = sc_group_discounts.item_group) 
LEFT JOIN 
    price ON (sc_products.product_code = price.item) AND (sc_products.suupplier=price.postavchik) 
WHERE 
    t26_replaceable_items.unicitem = 'maslo1' 
    AND sc_products.CatText = 'nut' 
    AND CASE 
           WHEN price.Price is null 
              THEN price is null 
              ELSE price.Price = (SELECT MIN(price.Price) 
                                  FROM price 
                                  WHERE price.unic = unicreplacement) 
        END 
GROUP BY 
    productID 
ORDER BY
    isnull (price.Price), price.Price ASC
```

It worked ok before I changed category for one product but now it returns no result. There are could be products with same code and different categories. What can I do about this?

Comment: Did you perhaps update CatText to something else?  Is the SQuirreL not finding 'nut'?

Comment: Well I thought about this, but it is present in sc_product table. If i query it it shows up okey.

Comment: I would at least try to approach this with a 'Try and error' method. Comment a where criteria, enclose the JOIN ... ON with (), complete the group by with all the columns you select...  Without knowing your data the only one who can debug this is you.